# How to select multiple Conditional Formatting rule in Manage Rules?

Tags: excel-2016

How do I select multiple conditional formatting rules in 'Manage Rules' in Excel?

I can't clear all rules because some are needed but there is a repeating rule that I want to delete which seems to be specified a few times. In Windows I am used to highlighting one thing, then SHIFT and UP arrow or holding down shift key and mouse click to select more than one.

Any help appreciated, its driving me insane!

[image: Manage Rules]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't need to remove any conditional formatting rules in the end.

For anyone interested I did two things.

1) For the one sheet that was freezing a lot, I ensured the same font was applied throughout the data.
2) I copied all the data from the sheet to a Word Document and then pasted back into the sheet.

Not sure why those worked but they did! The file was two thirds smaller and I didn't have to delete any CF rules.